# Date picker in Grails with JQuery UI: Resource not found error

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I am trying to use date picker from JqQuery UI in grails. My source files are

**ApplicationResources.groovy**

```
modules = {
    application {
        dependsOn 'jquery'
        resource url:'js/application.js'
        resource url:'css/main.css'
        resource url:'css/mobile.css'
    resource url:'css/mobile.css'
    }

    overrides {
        'jquery-theme' {
            resource id:'theme', url:'../plugins/jquery-ui-1.10.3/web-app/jquery-ui/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css'
        }
    }
}
```

And my **HTML** file includes the code

```
<r:require module="jquery"/>
<r:require module="jquery-ui"/>
<jqui:resources theme="blitzer" />
<r:script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'});
    })
</r:script>
```

When I load my HTML page, I get the following errors

```
Error 2014-06-24 12:25:35,766 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /plugins/jquery-ui-1.10.3/jquery-ui/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css
Error 2014-06-24 12:25:36,570 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /plugins/jquery-ui-1.10.3/jquery-ui/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css
Error 2014-06-24 12:25:36,631 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /plugins/jquery-ui-1.10.3/web-app/jquery-ui/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css
```

How can we resolve these errors and apply custom theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without attempting the defaults you are attempting to override your jquery-ui.
My recommendation is to try out the defaults and progress from there:
as per instructions: http://grails.org/plugin/jquery-ui

Install jquery-ui  by adding

> compile ":jquery-ui:1.10.3"

to your BuildConfig

> refresh-dependencies

Then add this to your main.gsp

```
<r:require module="jquery-ui"/>
```

see how that goes then attempt to override it